# Favicon and manifest.json is not loading in Django / React Project Setup

Tags: reactjs, django

I already have seen possible scenarios to solve this problem with the help of this already posted question and answer. [how-to-add-favicon-to-django-app-with-react-front-end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865159/how-to-add-favicon-to-django-app-with-react-front-end?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C61.2731)
But I'm unable to reproduce the solution.
Now the Problem is Favicon is generated automatically with a command: `npm run build`  In the build dir which the Django is serving.
This is how the build dir is generated after `npm run build` command

[image]

and the build is generated from this public folder

[image]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Site Title</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

After the command `python manage.py collectstatic`, Django servers all the files accurately except `manifest.json`

```
[20/Sep/2021 19:04:14] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 1344
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "ST",
  "name": "Site Name",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        #...
]
#...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

> So, I'm not sure how to configure my project to load manifest.json
> correctly and Is that file is responsible in this case to load favicon
> or by following another approach this can be resolved. Help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace this   `href="your image url"`
in `<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`
the reason why your favicon not loading is that it is not having the required permission my suggestion is to deal the favicons as you might be dealing with the images of your website just take any link of your website and paste it with in the href part and all shoul work fine

Comment: That's was so easy and I was just wasn't able to solve this. But yes you are right, with replacing the Image URL like `https:example.com/favicon.ico` instead of Auto-Generated URL `"%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"` from react create command. Thanks sarangkkl it's working now.